# How to transform string to date in Mulesoft?

Tags: mule

I have a mule flow that extracts data from MySQL to Salesforce. There is one field which is purchase_date. It's string in MySQL and needs to be mapped to purchase_date__c which is datetime in Salesforce.

In Datamapper, I just directly map them but the record cannot be inserted into Salesforce. How can I transform the datatype in this case? 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in datamapper select script button, 
in the corresponding input output mapping u can use the datamapper functions.
below is the function to convert date to string conversion
eg:

output.CreationDateAndTime =date2str(new java.util.Date(),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Hi are you using data mapper if not
You can use a small java component and convert the string to dateTime and invoke it as a variable